# segfault on ARM/Linux

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, ram

I have an application (Embedded OPC-UA server) compiled using "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-"  cross compiler tool chain.

The application runs as expected on Beagle Bone Black (GNU/Linux).

When I try to execute the application on a target platform similar to Beagle-Bone-Black with same processor the application throws a seg-fault. It doesn't even execute the first printf instruction in main.

What could be the Hardware/software constraints causing this behaviour ?
Is it possible because there is not enough free memory in RAM ?

Comment: This is pretty open-ended unless a lot of people have run into the same thing. Have you tried compiling and running something very simple and minimal?

Comment: I have compiled many simpler applications and they run fine. I also tried to debug using GDB but the backtrace stops due to corrupt frames. I am clueless actually.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to execute the application on a target platform similar to Beagle->Bone-Black with same processor the application throws a seg-fault. It doesn't >even execute the first printf instruction in main.

looks like `ld-linux` problem. Open your binary in any editor, and look at
substring `ld-linux`, for example on amd64 it looks like this: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, then check on similar platform, I suppose that it have different path of `ld-linux`, if you lucky then you just need create soft symlink, if not you have to rebuild your application.

Comment: Hi, I have created a folder structure. "/usr/local/lib" containing all required shared libraries. ../bin contains the executable.
I have a soft-link in "/lib" to the ld-linux. 

I think this is not a cause. I appreciate your suggestion and kindly tip me if you could think of something else.

Thanks

Comment: Aslo kernel send segfault signal to process, that call unknown system call.

Comment: Hi could you elaborate  ?

Comment: see bad_syscall function https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c?id=refs/tags/v4.4-rc2